# Converting object into number (array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, numbers

```
var hasil = [ T1:"56", T2:"90", T3:"20"]
```

I want that array to be like this `[56, 90, 20]` so I can use arithmetic operator like `56+90+20`.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: That is not valid JavaScript syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.values()` to convert to array of strings (`["56", "90", "20"]`), and `Array.reduce()` to sum the array. Since it's an array of strings, you'll need to convert each item to a number using the [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) operator:

```js
const hasil = { T1:"56", T2:"90", T3:"20" }
const result = Object.values(hasil)
  .reduce((s, n) => +s + +n)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `hasil` is an object and not an array, following code will give you array of values:

```js
var hasil = {T1:"56", T2:"90", T3:"20"}

let result = Object.values(hasil).map((value) => Number(value));

console.log(result)
```

**Edit**

As per @Ori Drori's suggestion, we can use following shorthand for converting string to number with map to get similar result:

```js
var hasil = {T1:"56", T2:"90", T3:"20"}

let result = Object.values(hasil).map(Number);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.values` to convert the object into array, `map` and pass `Number` as callback function

```js
let hasil = {T1:"56", T2:"90", T3:"20"}
let result = Object.values(hasil).map(Number);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean `var hasil = { T1:"56", T2:"90", T3:"20" }`, an Object. `Object.values(hasil)` will get what you want.